# Batch script, checking if folder exists fails inside loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, batch-file

I'm trying to check if several directories exists with a batch file, inside a loop, but it fails miserably.
The logic may seem a bit odd but I need those params like that for other processing which I omitted from the script for simplicity.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET output_path=C:\Users\test\Desktop\

SET scenario[0].param1=15
SET scenario[0].param2=100
SET scenario[0].param3=3600
SET scenario[1].param1=10
SET scenario[1].param2=1000
SET scenario[1].param3=3600

SET "i=0"

:CaseLoop
IF DEFINED scenario[%i%].param1 IF DEFINED scenario[%i%].param2 IF DEFINED scenario[%i%].param3 (

SET cur.param1=
SET cur.param2=
SET cur.param3=
FOR /f "delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in ('SET scenario[%i%]') do (
  SET cur.%%k=%%l
)

REM Check if output directory exists
CALL ECHO "%%output_path%%\%%cur.param1%%-%%cur.param2%%-%%cur.param3%%\"
IF EXIST "%%output_path%%\%%cur.param1%%-%%cur.param2%%-%%cur.param3%%\" (
  CALL ECHO SUCCESS
) ELSE (
  CALL ECHO NO
)
SET /a "i+=1"
GOTO :CaseLoop
)
```

The directories do exist but for some reason it enters the else statement.
I thought it could be the variable expansion but in the line before the ECHO echoes
`C:\Users\test\Desktop\15-100-3600\` and `C:\Users\test\Desktop\10-1000-3600\` respectively

Comment: The reason for that, is that `%%` interpreted as an escape for written `%`, so it actually checks for `%output_path%\%cur.param1%-%cur.param2%-%cur.param3%\`

Comment: It outputs the correct lines before the proving, because you use `call echo`, however you could just used `echo`, with a single `%` instead of `%%`

Comment: my best option is probably to `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and use `IF EXIST "%output_path%\!cur.param1!-!cur.param2!-!cur.param3!\"`

Comment: Yes, @znaya, because `call if` would not work…

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change the methodology, instead of enclosing the main part of the code into a, `IF DEFINED` parenthesized block, bypass the code for the opposite scenario, `IF NOT DEFINED`:

Example:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "output_path=C:\Users\test\Desktop"
Set /A scenario[0].param1=15, scenario[0].param2=100, scenario[0].param3=3600
Set /A scenario[1].param1=10, scenario[1].param2=1000, scenario[1].param3=3600
Set "i=0"

:CaseLoop
For /L %%G In (1,1,3) Do If Not Defined scenario[%i%].param%%G (GoTo :Next) Else Set "cur.param%%G="
For /F "Tokens=2,* Delims==." %%G In ('Set scenario[%i%]') Do Set "cur.%%H=%%I"
Rem Check if output directory exists
Echo "%output_path%\%cur.param1%-%cur.param2%-%cur.param3%"
If Exist "%output_path%\%cur.param1%-%cur.param2%-%cur.param3%\" (Echo SUCCESS) Else Echo NO
Set /A i += 1
GoTo CaseLoop

:Next
```